# ip6table-restore failed in Debian buster/sid

Tags: debian, iptables, nftables, ip6tables

I have the below iptable rule in `/etc/iptables/rule.V6` and `/etc/iptables/rule.V4`

```
-4 -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-6 -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
```

when I tried to restart the `netfilter-persistent`, it internally calls the `iptables-restore` and `ip6tables-restore`.

`ip6tables-restore` failed because it couldn't understand the below rule

```
-4 -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

Below is the error

```
root@rs-dal:/etc/iptables# ip6tables-restore rules.q
Error occurred at line: 15
Try `ip6tables-restore -h' or 'ip6tables-restore --help' for more information.
```

Ideally the rule that starts with `-4` will be ignored by the `ip6tables-restore`, but that doesn't seems to be working in Debian Buster.

But, `iptables-restore` worked fine, it is only the issue with `ip6tables-restore`.
How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are most certainly running iptables over nftables, as this is the default on Debian buster. To confirm this is the case, check for `(nf_tables)`:

```
# ip6tables-restore --version
ip6tables-restore v1.8.2 (nf_tables)
```

Now in the [ip6tables manual](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/iptables/ip6tables.8.en.html#PARAMETERS), there always has been:

> -4, --ipv4
>    This option has no effect in iptables and iptables-restore. If a rule using the -4 option is inserted with (and only with)
>   ip6tables-restore, it will be silently ignored. Any other uses will
>   throw an error. This option allows IPv4 and IPv6 rules in a single
>   rule file for use with both iptables-restore and ip6tables-restore.

The trouble is that you're now running [`ip6tables-nft-restore`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/iptables/ip6tables-nft-restore.8) rather than  [`ip6tables-legacy-restore`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/iptables/ip6tables-legacy-restore.8).

There is no mention of `-4` in [differences to legacy iptables](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/iptables/ip6tables-nft-restore.8#DIFFERENCES_TO_LEGACY_IPTABLES), meaning there shouldn't be a difference about it, but here it is. This really looks like a bug: either the new version `ip6tables-nft-restore` should cope with it, or the documentation should reflect it as an additional difference to be acceptable.

By the way the other way around (`-6` with `iptables-nft-restore`) doesn't look better: it's accepted instead of ignored, leading to `-A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT` in addition to `-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT` in IPv4 protocol (this will never happen, except maybe with a custom test, and the IP stack will ignore it anyway).

Possible workarounds:

1. file a bug report, insisting on a regression which would break existing rules and documentation. This would help other people too.
2. split rules

   split your file into two files but apply a different filter to each, something like:

   ```
   grep -v -- '^ *-4 ' < before > after.v6
   grep -v -- '^ *-6 ' < before > after.v4
   ```
3. create a wrapper for `ip6tables-restore` in `/usr/local/sbin/ip6tables-restore` doing about the same (and also do the same for `iptables-restore`), allowing to keep a single rule
4. Give up (for now) iptables over nftables and revert to legacy iptables:

   ```
   # readlink -f $(which ip6tables-restore)
   /usr/sbin/xtables-nft-multi
   # update-alternatives --config ip6tables        
   There are 2 choices for the alternative ip6tables (providing /usr/sbin/ip6tables).

     Selection    Path                        Priority   Status
   ------------------------------------------------------------
   * 0            /usr/sbin/ip6tables-nft      20        auto mode
     1            /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy   10        manual mode
     2            /usr/sbin/ip6tables-nft      20        manual mode

   Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
   update-alternatives: using /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy to provide /usr/sbin/ip6tables (ip6tables) in manual mode
   # readlink -f $(which ip6tables-restore)
   /usr/sbin/xtables-legacy-multi
   ```

   The link of the related command also changed, fine.

   Do the same with `iptables`.

   Current rules are still running over nftables. You can dump them with `iptables-nft-save` + `ip6tables-nft-save` and restore them with `iptables-save` + `ip6tables-save`. This will result in rules running twice: once with kernel's iptables backend, once with kernel's nftables backend, and NAT might not always work correctly with this on kernel 4.19 (usually the first loaded module wins: here `nft_nat)`. Better reboot, or know how to flush rules and remove relevant (nat) nftables modules.
5. embrace the new features and use directly [`nft`](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8).

   There are commands available to help here (but they have the same problem as above): [`iptables-translate`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-translate.8) / `ip6tables-translate` and `iptables-restore-translate` / `ip6tables-restore-translate`, but the result usually needs reworking anyway (especially with fancy matches like [`u32`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#u32)). Nftables has a family type [`inet`](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#ADDRESS_FAMILIES) which can actually mix IPv4 and IPv6 rules (might require a newer kernel for this in nat), so it would simplify things.

Comment: Thanks a lot the detailed explanation, will analyse all the workaround and update the thread about my next step.

Comment: I have raised a bug below is the link https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=925343

Comment: Good. The only possible missing thing is that you should show the documentation related to the `-4` option (from man iptables or man ip6tables), to insist this is a *documented* expected behaviour. Also understand that this report will probably be brought upstream at netfilter's team so this will take some delay anyway. Also the actual package is iptables, not iptables-persistent

Comment: The whole issue is started when I restarted netfilter-persistent. netfilter-persistent is in iptables-persistent package. the problem is actually on ip6table-restore, I should have specified the package as iptables. my bad it is my mistake. I will change it if possible

Comment: iptables 1.8.4 has a specific fix for your question (available in Debian sid but requires recompilation for Debian 10).